# How can I install a package in Gnu Octave?

Tags: command-line, package-management, software-installation, octave

How can I install a package in Gnu Octave? I have tried, for example, with the splines-package after downloading it in my home directory with:

```
Octave1>> pkg install splines-1.0.7.tar.gz
```

I get the following error message:

```
couldn't create installation directory /usr/share/octave/packages/3.2/splines-1.0.7     
: Permission denied
error: called from `pkg>copy_files' in file /usr/share/octave/3.2.4/m/pkg/pkg.m near line 1431, column 7
error: called from:
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.2.4/m/pkg/pkg.m at line 756, column 5
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.2.4/m/pkg/pkg.m at line 287, column 7
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

run Octave as SU:

```
sudo octave
```

and then try the same as You did.

Answer (score 0):

or `sudo -i` then `octave`
Before you run octave, you must download and store the package to /usr/share/octave/packages